# Quickly import local Maven packages into GitLab package registry?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, gitlab, gitlab-api

I'm currently trying to implement some CI/CD for an application. I have 3/4 docker images building fine, but one image is based on Gradle/Maven (instead of Flask like my others) and has custom library dependencies. I can build the image locally by setting the gradle file like so:

```
repositories {
    // Use JCenter for resolving dependencies.
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'lib'
    }
}

dependencies {
    // <Other dependencies here>
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

The problem I'm facing is I have a lot of local jar files I use for dependencies and I can't figure out a way to easily upload them to GitLab's Maven package registry.

I've been able to successfully upload one using `mvn deploy` and manually defining the path to it in `dependences`, but I don't want to do that for every single file, I'd like `implementation fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])` for them. What is the easiest way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

For custom dependency scopes, you might want to consider upgrading to Gradle from Apache Maven. Maven's behavior is conditioned per VERSION and it's individual properties. Which is why you are having to manually define the path to the file dependency.
Gradle is a library producer.
Maven is a library consumer.
Depending on what type of management you want for application's repository, you can find comparisons at https://gradle.org/maven-vs-gradle/

Hopefully this helps answer your question and find a better solution!